# Obfuscate .hex file

Tags: arduino-mega, compile

I've wrote a code for arduino mega, and want to force it from copying (this is commerce project). How can I obfuscate .hex file before uploading to arduino?

Comment: I think you are looking for [something like this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53282/protecting-avr-flash-from-reading-through-isp)